# how to using variables in search pattern in awk script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to print the pid when finding matched process while the match pattern is inputted:

```
ps aux | awk -v in="$1" '/in/{print $1}'
```

It seems the former awk sentence is not right. After checking many results in google like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk), I change my script in the following but still cannot work:

```
ps aux | awk -v in="$1" '/$0 ~ in/{print $1}'
```

or

```
ps aux | awk -v in="$1" '($0 ~ in) {print $1}'
```

Comment: I think `pgrep "$1"` would be better option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fairly close in all your attempts. Problem is that `in` is a reserved keyword in `awk`.

You can use:

```
ps aux | awk -v var="$1" '$0 ~ var {print $1}'
```

Or else non-regex way:

```
ps aux | awk -v var="$1" 'index($0, var) {print $1}'
```