# awk processing with a variable

Tags: regex, awk

input file is:

```
line1 [time-1] abcdef
line2 [time-1] absde1
line3 [time-1] abcdef
line4 [time-1] zzzzzz
```

this command is working fine:

```
$ str="abcdef|zzzzzz"
$ awk '!($0~/('"$str"')$/)' test_input
line2 [time-1] absde1
```

following command fails:

```
$ str="[time-1] abcdef|[time-1] zzzzzz"
$ echo "${str}"
[time-1] abcdef|[time-1] zzzzzz
$ awk '!($0~/('"$str"')$/)' test_input
awk: fatal: Invalid range end: /([time-1] abcdef|[time-1] zzzzzz)$/
$
```

Is it possible to pass variable with such string to awk too?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42131314/3776858

Comment: @Chris if `[time-1] abcdefgh` existed in your input file, should it get printed or not when `str="[time-1] abcdef"`? Can `str` contain any other regexp metachars like `.`, `?`, `{`, `+`, or `*`?

Comment: you're trying to do part literal part regex match.  You have to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more awk:

```
awk -v str="$str" 'BEGIN {
   n = split(str, a, "|")
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      if (index($0, a[i]))
         next
   print
}' file
```

```
line2 [time-1] absde1
```

Reason why you cannot just use `$str` as regex is that you have regex meta characters such as `[`, `]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to escape the square brackets

```
$ str="\[time-1\] abcdef|\[time-1\] zzzzzz"
$ awk '!($0~/('"$str"')$/)' test_input
line2 [time-1] absde1
```

--- Edit --------------------------

To create the str variable with escaped characters

```
str="[time-1] abcdef|[time-1] zzzzzz" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g'
```

This way, the pipe-separated list can be an automatically generated list.

Comment: unfortunately the pipe-separated list is built automatically..., I would need to escape all other cases which may happen...

Comment: maybe something like this: str="[time-1] abcdef|[time-1] zzzzzz" | sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g'